# First time with apport

Tags: indicator, time, apport

Today, when I turned on the laptop to update Ubuntu, I got an error "System program problem detected" after logging in. I thought it was an bug, so I updated the computer and restarted it, but the the error continued to appear.

Them, it asked for my password and I saw that the program was called "apport" (I think). After typing my password, I saw that the error was about the linux gnu time indicator, so I sent the file to Canonical (I think).

In the folder /var/crash, there is this file:

```
_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_indicator-datetime_indicator-datetime-service.112
```

(there are 3 different extensions for the same file, .crash, .upload, uploaded).

After that, I restarted my computer and the error stopped appearing,

So, since it is my first time with the program, I would like to know if this program is actually legit, and if my computer is alright.
EDIT: I would like to know too if it's possible to see the error window again, to see if I'm correct about the error being from apport.

Thank you guys for helping me, also sorry if there was another post like this.

Answer (score 1):

Apport is the tool that Ubuntu uses to report such errors; think of it like Ubuntu's version of Windows' error reporting. Yes, it is perfectly legit. As far as the problem re-occuring -- maybe, maybe not. Hard to say really. It may simply have been a one-time incident.

Comment: Good to know that it's legit. Also, do you know if it's possible to see again the error window again? Also, thank you for helping me.

Comment: It is entirely possible you might see the error again, that very same one I mean. However, I would not worry if I were you, if it was only in the date-time indicator.

Comment: Until now, the error didn't appeared again, strange. I can't even see my error reports.